# Consulta BD sem sobrecarregar o servidor

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Olá pessoal boa noite!

Preciso realizar várias consultas de um ID em uma tabela X, mais isso está sobrecarregando meu servidor e a conexão com a BD fica off, entrei em contato com o meu servidor e me informaram que está tento várias requisições e por isso fica offline.

Então gostaria de saber se é possível eu criar uma nova coluna e armazenar todas as informações e esquecer o relacionamento entre tabelas.

Como eu acho que não expressei a minha dúvida muito bem, vou deixa um fluxograma abaixo:
[image: Fluxo grama]

Já vi dados inseridos dessa forma mais não lembro como é, se alguém poder me ajudar com o nome da função ou um exemplo, agradeço muito.

@UPDATE
 Acho que encontrei o que queria pessoal, acho é o json_encode, vou ver como ele funciona, se não  for isso por favor me falem.

Comment: Vamos algumas perguntas basicas, que são as mais importantes: 1. Você tem acesso ao `root` do servidor? 2. Você tem a capacidade de alterar o `my.cnf` ou o arquivo de configuração do seu banco de dados? 3. Você está usando MySQL, qual banco de dados está usando? Prevendo possíveis respostas: Se não tiver acesso `root` possivelmente não há como corrigir de fato o problema, pois você não conseguirá alterar o `my.cnf`, na maioria dos casos. "Não existe" isso de "BD fica off", somente se estiver corrompida ou danificada (porque realmente desliga). Veja nos logs do MySQL o erro que apresentado.

Comment: O que um `json_encode` tem a ver com a performance de um BD?

Comment: Usando o json_encode eu posso salvar as informações da segunda tabela na primeira, certo? Segundo o que eu pensei fazendo isso deixaria meu banco de dados mais estável. Não sei o que realmente acontece, quando meu site passa de 1k online a conexão com o banco de dados  caí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim é possível.

O que você está querendo fazer é DESNORMALIZAR um banco de dados para ganho de performance.

Lembrando que não existe uma "receita de bolo" sobre normalização. Vai depender muito de cada situação.

Existem diversos artigos sobre isso na internet, a exemplo: [NORMALIZAÇÃO vs DESNORMALIZAÇÃO](http://edocaratti.blogspot.com.br/2008/02/normalizao-vs-desnormalizao-de-banco-de.html)

Lembre-se também de criar índices no banco de dados para campos que forem utilizados em filtros (`where`) ou ordenação (`order by`), pois isso vai ajudar na performance também.

Comment: Obrigado pela reposta educada, vou estudar o que você mencionou acima.